# PDF creation: continue long text on new page

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, multipage

I wand to bring a text from a UITextView on a PDF file.
I know how this works, but if the text is too long for the
page, it is cut.

How can I bring the excess text on a new page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how to split the text. Perhaps into sentences (separated by a period). Once you have decided that you can work through the text calculating the required layout height for the available width of the PDF. Once the text is calculated to be too high you can take the substring from the end of the previous sentence and add it to the PDF. Create a new page and continue the height based calculation (resetting the calculation variables) until all of the text is processed.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done so far. But if the tex is for example longer then 1000 characters this takes very long and often I get a memory warning.

Comment: Have you created the PDF so it saves to a file on disk? Then only 1 page is in memory at any one time...